# Kullback Leibler Divergence Property

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, machine-learning, information-theory

Let us define the arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic means of $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ weighted by $\alpha =(\alpha_x,\alpha_y) \in [0,1]$, respectively as

\begin{equation}
     a_\alpha(x,y) = \frac{\alpha_x x+\alpha_y y}{\alpha_x+\alpha_y}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
     g_\alpha(x,y) = x^\frac{\alpha_x}{\alpha_x+\alpha_y}y^\frac{\alpha_y}{\alpha_x+\alpha_y}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
     h_\alpha(x,y) = \frac{xy(\alpha_x+\alpha_y)}{\alpha_xy + \alpha_yx}
\end{equation}

Let us define the following information quantities (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.00610.pdf for more details on these quantities)

\begin{equation}
   A_\alpha(x,y) = \alpha_x \text{KL}\left(a_\alpha(x,y),x\right) + \alpha_y \text{KL}\left(a_\alpha(x,y),y\right) 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   G_\alpha(x,y) = \alpha_x \text{KL}\left(g_\alpha(x,y),x\right) + \alpha_y \text{KL}\left(g_\alpha(x,y),y\right) 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   H_\alpha(x,y) = \alpha_x \text{KL}\left(h_\alpha(x,y),x\right) + \alpha_y \text{KL}\left(h_\alpha(x,y),y\right) 
\end{equation}
where $\text{KL}(\cdot)$ is the Kullback-Leibler divergence. The Arithmetic-Geometric-Harmonic mean inequality is a very well known result that states

\begin{equation}
    a_\alpha(x,y) \geq g_\alpha(x,y) \geq h_\alpha(x,y)
\end{equation}
$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Given this inequality, and given that $x\geq y$, can we conclude that the the following is true?

\begin{equation}
     A_\alpha(x,y) \geq  G_\alpha(x,y) \geq  H_\alpha(x,y)
\end{equation}

Comment: What is the KL divergence for you? Is it $KL(x,y) = xlog(\frac{x}{y}) - x + y$?

Comment: It should be possible to prove it for a general KL between two distributions P,Q, of the type $\text{KL}(P,Q)=\sum _{x\in{\mathcal{X}}}P(x)\log \left({\frac {P(x)}{Q(x)}}\right)$.

Comment: For the case of poisson KL that you indicated in your comment I think it should follow directly from the monotonicity of log function. But is this true for in general for all distributions?

Comment: Yes I understand that but I am curious about your question specifically. Please be clear and precise in your question, i.e. define the KL divergence.